# How to describe recursion or a tree-like structure of arbitrary depth in a type annotation?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, typing

How do I describe a tree-like data structure, or a data structure containing recursion, in a type annotation?  The following may explain what I mean, but is invalid:

```
Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple[...]]]]]]
```

because of `TypeError: Tuple[t0, t1, ...]: each t must be a type. Got Ellipsis.`, which is fair enough.  One way would be to leave out the contents of the inner Tuple:

```
Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple]]]
```

or

```
Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple]]]]]
```

or

```
Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple[ndarray, Dict[Symbol, Tuple]]]]]]]
```

But those alternatives strictly specify the number of levels within the tree, whereas in reality this depth should not be specified.  The dictionaries can have arbitrary length (including length 0, which makes the depth finite).

How can I describe a tree of arbitrary depth but prescribed form, using the Python typing module?  Do I need to define my own generic type, or can I do this by combining existing generic types?

(Symbol is [`sympy.core.symbol.Symbol`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#id17), ndarray is [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray))

Comment: What you want here is "recursive types", and as of now it's not officially supported. Mypy is still working on them (see [their GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731)), and a comment there says that `pytest` by Google supports recursive types. I haven't used it so I can't be sure, but you might want to try it out.

Comment: @ZecongHu Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I'm happy that you find this comment helpful, but I don't think it qualifies as an answer since it didn't really solve your question. It would be better if people with more experience (e.g., have used `pytest` in projects) could answer this question.